# functions - passing element id as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

http://jsfiddle.net/vidhyaakrish/AFm89/64/

I am trying to pass an element id (eg.#target-elemet as parameter to  scroll_to(element))

```
function scroll_to(element){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(element).offset().top
    },1000);
    console.log(element);
}

scroll_to('"\#target-element\"');
```

but i am not able to achieve - Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
scroll_to('"\#target-element\"');
```

to

```
scroll_to('#target-element');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AFm89/65/)

Answer (score 1):

```
scroll_to("#target-element");
```

this should do it

Answer (score 1):

Your selector for the ID is not recognized by JQuery. (Here the # selector for the id)

Changing your code to this should help:

```
scroll_to('#target-element');
```

For some more insight on JQuery Selectos, see this link: [JQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Link to your updated Fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/holli_licious/AFm89/66/)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by creating a little jquery plugin:

```
$.fn.animateScrollToElement = function(speed, marginTop) {
    marginTop = marginTop || 0; // if not set, will be 0
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - marginTop
    }, speed);
    return this;
}
```

usage:

```
// element                        speed, 'margin top'
$( selector ).animateScrollToElement(1000, 20);
```

then you can use Standard jquery selector, the plugin function will handle the element by `this`.

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AFm89/67/**